# How do I make local js files work?

Tags: javascript, localhost

ON my local I am testing out stuff I've built.

This is the script I am trying to include in a file in the same folder:

```
<script src="/colorpicker/js/evol.colorpicker.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

The colorpicker is on my desktop in a folder called Work/demo/

The colorpicker is not working.  What an I do to make it work on my local?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of things (but mostly XMLHttpRequest) that can be done using JavaScript that will be blocked from `file:///` URIs for security reasons in some browsers. In general, for development purposes, I strongly recommend installing a web server (either directly on your workstation or in a virtual machine) and using that for testing.

That said, if you do want to test without a web server, then **don't use root relative URIs**. i.e. Do not start your URIs with a `/` character as that will hit the top of your file system, not the top directory that you consider to be part of your site.

Comment: One of the easiest ways to run a web server for development is python's SimpleHTTPServer. Simply install python on your system, and run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the directory you'd like to serve files from. Then browse to http://127.0.0.1:8000

Answer (score 0):

Since The script file is in the same folder with your HTML page, so you just have to include it with its file name only:

```
<script src="evol.colorpicker.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```